# Why VLC web plugin automatically clear its playlist?

Tags: javascript, html, vlc

I followed [this guide](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin), but it doesn't show how to dynamically change the plugin's source property, so I use the `Playlist` object.

I add some urls, then switch between them by `vlc.playlist.playItem`. It works fine when the `wrapper` is displayed.

When I call `$('#wrapper').hide()` then `$('#wrapper').show()`, I found the playlist is **emptyed** by some mysterious power.

So how should I properly keep the playlist and what is the right way to switch between videos?

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' id='vlc' toolbar='false' width='800' height='600' autoplay='false' />
</div>

var vlc = document.getElementById('vlc');
vlc.playlist.add('rtsp://asdfsdaf')
vlc.playlist.add('rtsp://1sfafdfa')
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [fbvlc](http://code.google.com/p/fbvlc/) now, it fixed those bugs of the vlc webplugin.